# Spark: partioning parquet by multiple values' column

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, parquet, partition

Within a Spark application that uses parquet in order to store a list of users. Each user has a phone number.

I need to search efficiently by phone, the best would be to partition by phone. Document says a key should have more than 10 000's of value, in my case this could be millions.

Is there yet any way / or any trick / or some state of the art to partition by phone number? For example hashing the phone number or partioning only by the first numbers?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you partitioned the mobile no by the first digit then data will be skewed. Because most of the mobile no start with the same digit or common digit.

Example in India, Mobile no. generally start with `9, 8 and, 7` and `60% of mobile start with 9, about 30-35% with 8`

Partition based on the last digit of mobile no will give you 10 partitions(`0-9`) without data skewness.